# UpdateView problem : cleaned data passed in url not in instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a problem with my update view but I can't figure out why it happens. So when I try to update an object with an UpdateView I don't get any error showing it just doesn't work and reload the page instead with the changed data passed into the url :

"[11/Dec/2018 11:49:20] "GET /home/update/vacation/421?csrfmiddlewaretoken=Op55u8r2GG2uyDjIvW2rstfedeU646ZkrJsmUOC6824rRO5W5NTT4koNwNCIBmof&poste_travail=poste+testa+modif&taux_marge=35.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 2887"

I tried to overwrite form_invalid and fom_valid to understand what is happening but it doesn't print anything

Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't work ?

### **views_class.py**

```
class VacationUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    form_class = VacationUpdateForm
    model = Vacation
    template_name = 'chiffrage/forms/vacation_update.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'vacation_id'

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.changed_data)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.data)
        vacation = form.save(commit=False)
        vacation.updated_by = self.request.user
        vacation.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('marge_prix', args=(
                                                self.object.version_contrat.contrat.site.client.slug(),
                                                self.object.version_contrat.contrat.site.client.pk,
                                                self.object.version_contrat.contrat.site.slug(),
                                                self.object.version_contrat.contrat.site.pk,
                                                self.object.version_contrat.contrat.slug(),
                                                self.object.version_contrat.contrat.id,
                                                self.object.version_contrat.slug(),
                                                self.object.version_contrat.id)))
```

### **forms.py**

```
class VacationUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vacation
        fields = ['poste_travail', 'taux_marge']
```

### **urls.py**

```
path('update/vacation/<int:vacation_id>', views_class.VacationUpdate.as_view(), name='vacation_class_update'),

path('clients/<slug:client_name>,<int:client_id>/<slug:site_name>,<int:site_id>/<slug:contrat_slug>,<int:contrat_id>/<slug:version_slug>,<int:version_id>/prix', views.vacation_add,
     name='marge_prix'),
```

### **vacation_update.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} {{ request.user }}{% endblock %}
{% block ligne-titre %}{{ client }}{% endblock %}
{% block sans-div %}
<div class="main container-fluid col-8">

<form class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token%}
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">

    {{ form.as_table }}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input class="align-self-center btn btn-secondary " type="submit" value="Nouveau"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the `method` set for your form. This means that the form is using the default method of `GET` to submit.

Try changing `vacation_update.html` to:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} {{ request.user }}{% endblock %}
{% block ligne-titre %}{{ client }}{% endblock %}
{% block sans-div %}
<div class="main container-fluid col-8">

<form class="form-group" method="post">
    {% csrf_token%}
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">

    {{ form.as_table }}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input class="align-self-center btn btn-secondary " type="submit" value="Nouveau"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```